# Django template: sorting subset: _set.all

Tags: django, templates

In a django template, for each category, I iterate through each subcategory. But how do I sort the subcategories? I need it to be flexible so I can choose what I sort on.

```
{% for cat in categories %}  
     {% for subcat in cat.subcategories_set.all%}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dictsort` template tag, it lets you can sort by any of the keys. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#dictsort)